# Installing gcc 4.1.0 on ubuntu

Tags: gcc, ubuntu

I have latest version of `ubuntu`, but the version of `gcc` is higher than what I want. How do I build `gcc 4.1.0` or install `gcc 4.1.0` on this.
I did not find steps to build `gcc 4.1.0`

Comment: Why do you want to downgrade GCC?  Does the new version complain too much about the code you're compiling?

Comment: Also note that installing and building with an older gcc will not be sufficient to run on an older OS version.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps to building gcc:

http://gcc.gnu.org/install/

Note that, while "It refers to the current development sources, instructions for specific released versions are included with the sources."

It is a typical* configure, make, make install process. The most important configure flag is probably `--enable-languages`. and `--prefix` of course. Also `--program-suffix=-4.1` will cause the generated executable to be called gcc-4.1 instead of gcc. The prerequisites list may look scary but most of it is optional, especially if only building for C/C++.

[*] ok, not so typical: another caveat pointed out by JonathanWakely in the comments below is that you shouldn't build gcc in the source dir since that is not supported, so :

(after getting all the prerequisites)

```
[gcc-src-dir] $ cd ../my-build-dir
[my-build-dir] $ ../gcc-src-dir/configure $CONFIG_FLAGS
[my-build-dir] $ make
[my-build-dir] $ make install
```

And he pointed to a wiki page he wrote which will walk you through the whole process.

Comment: AFAICR, the pre-requisites MPFR, GMP, and MPC are not optional, at least when building later versions of GCC.  There's a decent chance that they're covered already; the current versions will be more recent than expected, but are unlikely to cause actual problems.

Comment: Beware multiarch! As of Ubuntu 11.10 the standard locations for system libraries have been gradually moving around. Even current GCC cannot be built without modification, and GCC 4.1 even more so.

Comment: @spam_eggs, building GCC is **not** a typical configure, make, make install process in one important respect: you should **not** build in the source directory, i.e. do `../gccsrc/configure` and not `./configure` ... I wrote a [wiki page](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC) describing the process, for GCC 4.1 the `download_prerequisites` script doesn't exist, so manually download GMP and MPFR (not MPC) and put the sources under the GCC source dir in directories called `gmp` and `mpfr` respectively.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Interesting, last time I did a build I happened to be building from a staging directory, which is a good discipline I don't always follow :) Why is this so important to the gcc build? I'll update my answer with the info ..

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, for GCC 4.1 MPC is not needed at all, GMP and MPFR are only needed if building the Fortran front-end.

Comment: @spam_eggs, it's unsupported and not well tested and so sometimes breaks for weird reasons, also as I wrote on the wiki page linked above, "A major benefit of running _srcdir/configure_ from outside the source directory (instead of running ./configure) is that the source directory will not be modified in any way, so if your build fails or you want to re-configure and build again, you simply delete everything in the _objdir_ and start again."

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Thanks for the correction — it's a long time since I built GCC 4.1.0.  I have the 4.1.2 source from Feb 2007, and 4.0.0 from April 2005, so 4.1.0 probably falls between those dates.  It is old!

Comment: Yep, I had to look in an old set of  docs to find how GMP and MPFR were used. The [development timeline](http://gcc.gnu.org/develop.html#timeline) gives Feb 2006 for GCC 4.1.0

Comment: @JonathanWakely Thanks, updated my answer! Agree it is always good practice to build in a seperate dir.

Comment: I've also written a blog post which describes the exact build steps (when not using the `download_prerequisites` script): http://advogato.org/person/redi/diary/240.html

Answer (score -1):

I had a few issues installing gcc 4.1.2 on ubuntu (12.04 in my case).  This script sorted it for me:

```
#!/bin/tcsh

if ($#argv != 1) then
    echo "Synopsis: $argv[0] <install_dir>"
    exit(-1)
endif

setenv GCCINSTALL $argv[1]
setenv LIBRARY_PATH /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
setenv SRC ~/gccSrc

mkdir -p $SRC
cd $SRC
wget http://gcc.cybermirror.org/releases/gcc-4.1.2/gcc-4.1.2.tar.gz
tar xvf gcc-4.1.2.tar.gz
cd gcc-4.1.2
mkdir build
cd build
../configure --prefix=${GCCINSTALL} --disable-multilib
grep 4.1.2/missing Makefile
sed -i "s#${SRC}/gcc-4.1.2/missing##" Makefile
grep 4.1.2/missing Makefile
make bootstrap
make install
```